# Multi-Region Availability for Postgres Database to be able to offer our clients 4+ 9's of availability?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, high-availability

We use Google Cloud SQL, and when deployed in High Availability mode, it offers an SLA of 99.95%. Google offers its high availability still within the same region, just in a different zone. We have clients who are asking for an SLA of 99.99%, and are willing to pay for 99.999%.

The only thing we've thought of is creating a read replica in another region that we could fail over to if there is such an outage. Such a fail over would be manual though. We would have to 1. Take down our primary database. 2. Promote the read replica 3. Redeploy our servers, changing the environment variable for our database.

With everything being so manual, it seems difficult to be able to offer this as part of our SLA, as such a change would take ~30 minutes. We would need to setup something to be automatic.

Surely this isn't a common problem. There has to be a better way to achieve higher availability for postgres. What do other companies do?

Comment: 1/2) You mention that you have customers willing to pay for **five nines**.  I have never seen a public database service that offers five nines. The cost would be x100 to x1000 times more. Only very large enterprises can build and maintain such systems.

Comment: 2/2) 99.99% uptime means only 1 minute per week of downtime. This includes the time you need to spend patching operating systems, updating software, backing up, etc. Can you do all of that in 1 minute each week? If not, you won't achieve 4 nines (99.99%). Make a mistake and your 4 nines goal will become two nines.

Comment: Maintenance windows don't apply to the SLA

Comment: even being able to offer 4 9's would be better than what we can currently offer of 99.95%

Comment: You will not achieve even 99.95% end-to-end in the real world using cloud services. I design and build these types of systems and the budgets and staff required are significant. Unless money is no object, three-nines is pretty good and that is what you should design to.

Comment: Thank you for your sobering advice. I appreciate your practical answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been managing PostgreSQL High Availability cluster. We did failover test on VMWare on premise with multi region deployment. You need below steps for failover:

1. Promote standy server which is there in DR region using `pg_promote`
2. Run `CHECKPOINT` on promoted done, so that other nodes who will join this newly promoted nodes gets upto date information.
3. Join other cluster nodes with this newly promoted node using `pg_rewind` for diff syncing only. If you deploy new node, then need to use `pg_basebackup` to join this new node.

Bonus TIP: If replication slot is supported, then you should create replication slot for every other cluster nodes as soon as you perform step 1.

All above steps need to perform as a sidecar monitoring using some tool

Comment: How does your answer provide four-nines of availability, which is the question asked?